# AlarmManager firing Alarm Instantly

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Alarm.this, Automaton.class);
                  myIntent.putExtra("methodName", "myMethod");
                  myIntent.putExtra("hour", tp.getCurrentHour().toString());
                  myIntent.putExtra("minute", tp.getCurrentMinute().toString());
                  hour = tp.getCurrentHour();
                  minute = tp.getCurrentMinute();
                  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Alarm.this, 0, myIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                       Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                       calendar.set(calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                       calendar.set(calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                       calendar.set(calendar.SECOND, 0); 
                       alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 86400000, pendingIntent);
```

Above is my code.  Here is my problem; I have a method in another Activity that I want to run at a specified time.  If the user selects a time that HASN'T passed yet in the day (say you set the alarm at 10AM for 11AM, it will work fine).  However, if you set the alarm for 9AM at 10AM, it will instantly fire the Pending Intent.  Not sure where I am going wrong.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You might need to check whether the `set time` is less than the `current time`. If the set time is less than current time, don't set an alarm for it. Because it's useless even if you keep it when the time has already passed.

Comment: thank you for the quick response Appu, lets say I want to set an alarm  now (11:45PM) to run tomorrow at 5:30AM.  Technically 5:30AM has already passed, so if I go to set it, it'll fire instantly.  That's what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: No, I can say the way you understand the things is wrong. Because the alarms should be set with the help of milliseconds. So 11.45PM now in milliseconds is less than 5:30AM(in milliseconds) tomorrow technically :)

Answer (score 2):

you can take calendar instance and set the date to the next day and use it with the alarm.

Answer (score 0):

To what @shreyas said, you need to do the check yourself if you need to bump the day.

Example.. If they select 5:00PM (HOUR_OF_DAY = 17) compare that to current time. If that time (17) is less that the current time, then add a day to your calendar instance.

> ```
> int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
> calendar.set(calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek + 1);
> ```